# Kivy: how do I make shapes drawn out of lines(multiple points) on my canvas moveable/draggable

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

hello I just started learning kivy, I found a way to move ellipse from another post [Moving multiple Widgets in Kivy independently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52507695/moving-multiple-widgets-in-kivy-independently) but I wish to move lines(multiple points) and drawings(make out of lines) instead. how do I go about doing this

the code from the post shown below

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Ellipse, Color
from kivy.core.window import Window
from random import randint


class CircleWidget(Widget):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CircleWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.size = (50, 50)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(0, 0, 1, 0.5)
            self.circle = Ellipse(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
        self.bind(pos=self.redraw, size=self.redraw)

    def redraw(self, *args):
        self.circle.size = self.size
        self.circle.pos = self.pos

    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            # if the touch collides with our widget, let's grab it
            touch.grab(self)

            # and accept the touch.
            return True

        return super(CircleWidget, self).on_touch_down(touch)

    def on_touch_up(self, touch):
        # check if it's a grabbed touch event
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            # don't forget to ungrab ourself, or you might have side effects
            touch.ungrab(self)

            # and accept the last up
            return True

        return super(CircleWidget, self).on_touch_up(touch)

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        # check if it's a grabbed touch event
        if touch.grab_current is self:
            self.pos = touch.pos

            # and accept the last move
            return True

        return super(CircleWidget, self).on_touch_move(touch)


class RootWidget(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RootWidget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(8):
            self.add_widget(CircleWidget(pos=(randint(0, Window.width - 50), randint(0, Window.height - 50))))


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just redraw whatever you want in the `redraw()` method. for example, your circles can be redrawn like this:

```
def redraw(self, *args):
    self.canvas.clear()
    with self.canvas:
        Color(0, 0, 1, 0.5)
        Ellipse(pos=self.pos, size=self.size)
```

Comment: sorry, how do I go about it if I want to redraw lines for example using Line(points=(750, 790, 770,790)) instead of Ellipse

Comment: Replace `Ellipse` with `Line`.

Comment: I tried but I didn't work thanks for the help